Find forward fundamental solution
I am studying for an exam and I've come across a practice problem that asks me to find the forward fundamental solution for
$$\partial_t u - \partial_x^2 u = -2i \partial_x u - u$$
in $(0, \infty)_t \times \mathbb{R}_x$. I've rewritten the equation as
$$\left( \partial_t^{1/2} - \left( \partial_x - i \right) \right) \left( \partial_t^{1/2} + \left( \partial_x - i \right) \right) u = 0$$
but I don't think this gets me anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. A forward fundamental solution is a distribution $E_+$ that satisfies
$$\left( \partial_t - \partial_x^2 + 2i \partial_x + 1 \right) E_+ = \delta_0$$
and $E_+ = 0$ for $t < 0$.

Hint. Make the substitution $u=e^{ix}v$.

With substitution $u(x,t)=e^{i x}\cdot v(x,t)$ one will get the heat equation: $v_t=v_{xx}$

Standard prodedure: Fourier transform in x
$$\left(- \partial_x^2 \ + \ 2 i \ \partial_x \ +\ 1\right) e^{i k x}\  = \ (k-1)^2 \ e^{i \ k \ x}$$
Solve
$$f'[t] + (k - 1)^2 f[t] = 0  \ \leftarrow  \  f(t) = e^{-(k-1)^2 t}$$
The Fourier transform yields the complex Gaussian
$$ \mathcal{F}(k\to  e^{-(k-1)^2 \ t }) (x) =\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{4 t}+i x}}{ \sqrt{2 t}} $$
Normalize to 1 at $t \ to +0$
